# Summing up all repeated values in a dataset

Tags: python, r, dataset, data-analysis

I have a dataset in which in a column I have the name of a person and in another column I have the amount she was paid for a given service. I'd like to build a list with the names of all people ordained by the total amount they were paid regardless of the service they performed. Example:

```
Ann     100
John    200
Matt    150
John    150
John    150
Ann     300
Erik    150

===========
John    500
Ann     400
Matt    150
Erik    150
```

I figured this involves looking for all repeated instances of the name of the person and then storing the value paid on the column, eventually summing up everything. The problem is I have too big of a list and can't check individual names. That is, I can't define a particular string for each name to be checked, rather I'd like the program to figure the repeated instances by itself and return the ordained list in the manner that I described. Is there any way to do this? I know a bit of Python and R so any method described in these languages would be particularly helpful.

Comment: For an R method, pick your favorite answer at the [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061) FAQ. I would suggest `library(dplyr); your_data %>% group_by(name) %>% summarize(value = sum(value))`, filling in your actual column names where I have use `name` and `value`.

Comment: Thanks, I know now what approach to take!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made your dataset into a pandas dataframe this is easily done with groupby

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':names, 'paid':paid})


total_pay = df.groupby(by='name').sum()
```

Comment: Having a small issue, the sum seems to be concatenating the numbers instead of summing then. Is there any way to solve this? My numbers are in the format XXX.YYY,ZZ.

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out. Just had to convert "." to "", "," to "." and use agg(lambda x: x.astype(float).sum()).

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Using the `mtcars` data in R, **a base R approach** would be to use the `tapply()` function and isolate vectors of your name and value data (cyl and hp respectively here)

```
tapply(mtcars$hp, mtcars$cyl, sum)
```

---

**2.** I'd personally use **a data.table approach** - data.tables are fast and the syntax is (I think) intuitive and readable whilst being concise

```
library(data.table)
dtcars <- data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames=TRUE)
dtcars[, sum(hp), keyby=cyl]
```

The data.table is in essence a data.frame on steroids — it can do way more than the base R data.frame and far more efficiently. Variables can be referred to by name (e.g. `cyl` instead of `mtcars$cyl`) from within the square braces. The notation `dt[i, j, by]` describes the basic functionality — `i` is used to sort or subset data (`dtcars[order(mpg)]`), `j` is used to select or process variables (`dtcars[, mean(mpg)]`) and `by` (and `keyby` to sort the output) allow the `j`-operation to be done by grouping variables. Note you'll first need to convert the data.frame to a data.table using `setDT()` or `data.table()`.

---

**3.** Or you could used **a tidyverse approach**, piping data from statement to statement.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(sum(hp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

df<-data.frame("Name" = c("Ann", "John", "Matt", "John", "John", "Ann", "Erik"), "val"=c(100, 200,150, 150, 150, 300,150))

df <- data.table(df)
df[ , .(val= sum(val)), by = "Name" ]

   Name val
1:  Ann 400
2: John 500
3: Matt 150
4: Erik 150
```

Comment: Clever, I was thinking of something like this in R, but didn't know how to pull it off. Thank you!